# Jupyter Notebook does not open normally after Windows OS setup and reinstalling Anaconda

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I usually start Jupyter Notebook as instructed in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JId0f7URtOQ

It worked fine up until last week when I reinstalled my OS and reinstalled Anaconda.

Now, when I do the same thing it opens Edge browser and does "Bing" search "jupyter notebook" instead. I can still start jupyter notebook by typing "jupyter notebook" directly into Anaconda Prompt.

How do I make it work like the video again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe anaconda changed the way it installs on Windows recently (somewhere in 2017 I would say). It used to add itself to the `PATH`; it does not anymore. More precisely, adding to the `PATH` is now an option during install, which is off by default. It comes with a big scary red warning that would discourage most users of doing so.

To add anaconda again in the path, you could install it again, or add the following folders to your path,

```
?
?\Scripts
?\Library\bin
```

where `?` is the root of your installation (e.g. `C:\Program Files\Miniconda3`).

Comment: Yes, I think I saw the warning and chose the default option, what's the issue with adding anaconda to Path?

Comment: If jupyter is not in the path, it cannot find it when you type it in explorer.

Comment: last question, if I just install Anaconda again in the same location it will just overwrite everything as if I install it the first time right? Will I have to worry about leftovers from previous installation and such

Comment: Yes, you should be fine uninstalling and reinstalling.